# ListView with AlertDialog Validation

Tags: android, android-listview

How can I apply validation to a ListView using an AlertDialog?  My scenario is this, I need to have the user select the State from which they are doing a search from.  The values of the State are defined in a spinner.  If the user clicks on a Listview item without selecting a state I have defined an AlertDialog below.

The problem I am encountering is that the alert box displays but does not stop the execution of the underlying task.

How can I stop the execution of my AsyncTask until the user has selected a State from the spinner?  Are there any examples showing how to validate that the user has made a selection from a spinner prior to kicking off an AsyncTask?

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View itemClicked, int position, long id) {

                // This code executes just fine but runs asynchronous with my SearchProducts task.
                String selectedState = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                if(selectedState.equals("Choose Your State")) {
                    alertbox("State", "Please Choose Your State");
                }           

                String strText = items[position];

                if (strText.equalsIgnoreCase(getResources().getString(R.string.menu_search))) {
                    new SearchProducts().execute();
```

This is my AlertDialog code.

```
protected void alertbox(String title, String mymessage) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
           .setMessage(mymessage)
           .setTitle(title)
           .setCancelable(true)
           .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel,
              new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton){}
              })
           .show();
        }
```

Comment: Can you rewrite it such that you either show the dialog or start the async task rather than showing the dialog and starting the async task every time?

Answer (score 0):

I feel like such an amateur, I have implemented the dialog in the correct manner.  What I was missing from my code was a "return" statement on my onClick for the AlertDialog.  The updated code looks like this.

```
protected void alertbox(String title, String mymessage) { 
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this) 
           .setMessage(mymessage) 
           .setTitle(title) 
           .setCancelable(true) 
           .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, 
              new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton){
                  return;
              } 
              }) 
           .show(); 
        }
```